# Is it possible , looping through array and assigning `<a href ="" ></a>` to every element in the array, and assigning it to one variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a array with two image tags in it `["cat" , "animal" ]` . I want to hyperlink every element in the array and assign it to one variable. The image tags are changing depending on the image clicked. That means they can be 1 ,2 ,3 or more tags stored in the array every time a different image is clicked. 
I want to display every image tag as hyper link where when i t is clicked to execute a function. 
I do it with `For Loop` , but every time only the last tag is displayed (Tag: dog ), the other one are not .
With `forEach` method , the whole array is displayed as one tag again , the other one i `undefined` ( Tag: cat,undefined)

JS:

```
for(let i =0 ; i <imgTag.length ; i++) {
           imgTags = (`<a href="" onclick="goToItem()">${imgTag[i]}</a>`);
        }

 imgTag.forEach(function(elem) {
            imgTags = (`<a href="" onclick="goToItem()">${elem}</a>`);
        });
```

Can someone tell me where am i wrong? Also i can take it even if every element is assigned to a different variable , depending on how elements there are every time a different image is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration you are assigning (`=`) the current tag to the variable *imgTags* which removes the previous tag.  You should use `+=` to keep the previous tags:

```
imgTags += `<a href="" onclick="goToItem()">${imgTag[i]}</a>`;
```

Comment: Aaahhh , got it , yes , amateur miss . Thank you :)

Comment: @User2445, you are most welcome:)

Answer (score 1):

As @Mamun already mentioned you are overwriting and not appending each `a` tag to the last container variable.
See the code below

```
tags = ['cat','dog']; // initial array
imgTags = [];         // final container array

tags.forEach(function(item) {
    e = document.createElement('a'); // create element
    e.href = "#";                   // add href
    e.innerText = item;             // add text node
    e.onclick = "gotoItem()";       // add onclick
    imgTags.push(e);                // add element to container array
});

console.log(imgTags);   // print out container, expand to see all
console.log(imgTags[1]) // print second element in container array
```